# Manual Mapping with Inhertance

Tags: c#, inheritance, mapping, extension-methods, dto

let assume I have two classes A and ADto.
A inherits from ABase and ADto inherits from ADtoBase.

I have two extension methods for manually mapping ABase to ADtoBase and vice versa.
When I want to write an extension method to map A to ADto, is there any way to reuse the base conversation to avoid duplication? i.e. I don't want to right mapping for the fields that exist in the base class and somehow reuse the base mapper for that.

Example:

```
Class ABase:
+ string Id;

Class ADtoBase:
+ string Id;

Class A: ABase:
+ string Name;

Class ADto:ADtoBase
+ string Name

public static ADto ToADto(this ADtoBase)
{
// I somehow want to use the base mapper (extension) so that I don't have to map Id again and only map Name.
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you presented it with actual class definitions instead of quasi-UML (or whatever you're trying to do there).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method like this:

```cs
void MapBaseClassProperties(ABase source, ADtoBase target) // Awful method name!
{
    target.Id = source.Id;
    target.Name = source.Name;
}
```

The mapping method for the inherited type can create an instance of the target type and map whatever properties are *not* in the base classes.

Then it can pass both the original and the mapping "target" to a method which does the mapping for the base class properties. In other words, this:

```cs
public Adto MapToDto(A source)
{
    var target = new Adto();
    // map the properties that aren't in the base class
    target.SomeOtherProperty = source.SomeOtherProperty;

    // map the properties that are in the base class.
    MapBaseClassProperties(source, target);
    return target;
}
```